# Android: Opening an Office document without the local copy

Tags: android, excel, android-intent, ms-word, powerpoint

Background:
We're working on an app which can securely download files from a server and allow users to view the files on their Android device (as long as they have Word/Excel/Powerpoint installed) - we specifically target the Microsoft products as they shouldn't "leak" information to a third party.

Using an Intent to open the file in the relevant application, and when we return to our app we revoke the URI read permission.

The problem is that when you open a document in them they make a local copy of the file, so the files can be re-opened without having to go through our app's security.

As an example, the document in the "Recent" list on Word has the location as:

```
≫ data ≫ user ≫ 0 ≫ com.microsoft.office.word ≫ documents ≫ document.docx
```

Obviously we'd like to stop this, does anyone know how to stop Android Office from making a "local cache" copy of the file?

Our code that opens the files looks like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, appContext.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
}
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.setPackage(appPackage);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
activity.grantUriPermission(appPackage, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

appPackage is the package name of the application as the same code is used for Word, Excel and Powerpoint.

Note that the files can be in doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt or pptx, as the documents can be historic.

Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: You might want to explain further your use case. If the app is not under your control - the app can do anything (i.e. make copies).

Comment: `Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide.` ? We are not in here for thank in advance.